# How to copy and paste into new worksheet (VBA) with values only

Tags: excel, vba

Currently the code I am using does not copy and paste values only.  I need something changed in the code so this function can be applied.

```
'Copy & Paste this data in to our new worksheet:
 wbURL.Sheets(3).Cells.Cut Destination:=wbMe.Sheets("NPMIG Data Sheet").Range("A1")
'Close the downloaded version which we no longer need
```

Comment: Change `Cut` to `Copy`?  If you want values, use `PasteSpecial` (on a new line applied to the `wbMe.Sheets...Range`) instead of the `Destination`.  This is a very very common task on this site and across the internet.  Am I missing something in your goal or did you post here first instead of searching for an answer?

Comment: 'Copy & Paste this data in to our new worksheet:
    wbURL.Sheets(3).Cells.Copy
    wbMe.Sheets("NPMIG Data Sheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial        (xlPasteValues)

Comment: Eventually what I came up with (above).
For some reason I just couldn't get to the solve even after reading site after site on the internet.
None of them really explained/told that this should be separated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wburl.Sheets(3).cells.Copy
worksheets("NPMIG Data Sheet").Range("A1").PasteSpecial.Values
```

Would be my thought. You might have to tighten up the worksheet references a bit though.